# react-box call of create data function returns invalid address

Tags: truffle-contract, react

[error image](https://www.screencast.com/t/ivCR8ube1lK) indicates invalid address.  this is on the call of the function.  Ideas on why it fails?  i suspect i'm missing something simple.

Function:

```
createCredentialOrg(event){
    alert("Attempting Create");
    const credentialOrgFactoryContract = this.state.credentialOrgFactoryContract
    var checkBool = this.state.web3.isAddress(this.state.createCredentialOrgSchoolAddress)
    var a,b,c;

    if (checkBool){
      a = this.state.createCredentialOrgShortName;
      b = this.state.createCredentialOrgOfficialSchoolName;
      c = this.state.createCredentialOrgSchoolAddress

      alert(a);
      alert(b);
      alert(c);
      return credentialOrgFactoryContract.createCredentialOrg(a, b, c)
     .then(result => {
        alert(result);
        return credentialOrgFactoryContract.selectOrgCount()
     }).then ((result) => {
        alert(result)
        this.setState({credentialOrgCount: result.c[0]})

     })
   } else {
      alert("invalid address");
      alert(a);
      alert(b);
      alert(c);
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `this.state.createCredentialOrgSchoolAddress`? Can you just simplify your code down to `web3.isAddress('0x123...')` so others can reproduce it?

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/hTIytkN5EBY
the highlighted address is the one that is passed into it, from ganache  

[github repository](https://github.com/shaddow1201/CredentialVerify)   
 screenshot also shows address, but here it is in text: 0x1eC2c24e0110a0c0C4e0E03e694dBC95cd825162

Comment: Rather than guess, why don't you just `console.log` the address right before you use it (or better yet, hardcode it as I suggested). The goal is to narrow down where the issue is. (Is that address somehow invalid? Or is the address you're checking not what you think it is?)

Comment: it's NOT a guess.  i do alert it, and it shows appropriately.  added console.log for c, and removed alerts, and it's the same.   And it DOES log appropriately, per:
https://www.screencast.com/t/cvVb7WB8  

it's also a valid address per the blockchain ganache image.

Comment: Could you please just try `web3.isAddress('0x1eC2c24e0110a0c0C4e0E03e694dBC95cd825162')`? It returns `true` in web3.js 0.20.3. If it returns `true` in your app too, that's further evidence that you're not actually passing the value you think you're passing. Once you determine you're not passing the right address, a good trick to try is `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.createCredentialOrgSchoolAddress))`. That might help spot other issues, like an extra space or an invisible unicode character.

Comment: Also, please share actual output, not screenshots. (Screenshots are inaccessible, can't be searched, and tend to disappear depending  on where they're hosted.)

Comment: i think you may have missed CheckBool, it's against isAddress and returns TRUE OR you wouldn't get into that area to MAKE the call.  I'll look at accommodating your preferences in the future, editing in this environ is limited.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. So you're not reaching the line that alerts "invalid address?" Could you explain where you're encountering an error?

Comment: Injected web3 detected.  
App.js:173 0x1eC2c24e0110a0c0C4e0E03e694dBC95cd825162  
App.js:174 "0x1eC2c24e0110a0c0C4e0E03e694dBC95cd825162"  
formatters.js:271 Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid address
    at inputAddressFormatter (formatters.js:271)

Comment: Maybe you just don't have `web3.eth.defaultAccount` set to anything?

Comment: ok, now i think we may be getting somewhere.  please expound on the web3.eth.default account.  The error occurs on the contract function call:

        return credentialOrgFactoryContract.createCredentialOrg(a, b, c)

Comment: You're sending a transaction without specifying a `from` address, so it should be using `web3.eth.defaultAccount`. If that's undefined, then you're trying to send from an invalid address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per: [smartx](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/19510/smarx) and the last comment: web3.eth.defaultAccount was undefined and thus causing the attempted send to occur out being attached to an account (thus invalid address)

thanks for the help!